# Access kubernetes cluster from outside of the host machine via port 80

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, bare-metal-server

So, instead of explaining the architecture I draw you a picture today :) *I know, it's 1/10.*

*Forgot to paint this as well, it is a **single node cluster***

Hope this will save you some time.
Probably it's also easier to see where my struggles are, as I expose the lack of understandings.

So, in a nutshell:

> **What is working:**
>
> - I can curl each ingress via virtual hosts from *inside* of the server using `curl -vH 'host: host.com' http://192.168.1.240/articleservice/system/ipaddr`
> - I can access the server

---

> **What's not working:**
>
> - I can *not* access the cluster from *outside*.

Somehow I am not able to solve this myself, even tho I read quite a lot and had lots of help. As I am having issues with this for a period of time now explicit answers are really appreciated.

[image: architecture]

Comment: when you say `access the cluster`, are you trying to access K8s APIs from outside ?

Comment: Yes. So e.g. calling a method which is inside one  of the pods containers.

Comment: You need to forward the load balancer port from the host

Comment: Okay, that was my idea as well. Even tho, I have no approach to do that yet. Can I realize that using `iptables`?

Answer (score 2):

Generally you cannot access your cluster from outside without exposing a service.
You should change your "Ingress Controller" service type to `NodePort` and let kubernetes assign a port to that service.
you can see ports assigned to a service using `kubectl get service ServiceName`.
now it's possible to access that service from out side on `http://ServerIP:NodePort` but if you need to use standard HTTP and HTTPS ports you should use a reverse proxy outside of your cluster to flow traffic from port 80 to `NodePort` assigned to Ingress Controller Service.
If you don't like to add reverse proxy, it is possible to add `externalIPs` to Ingress controller service but in this way you lose `RemoteAddr` in your Endpoints and you get ingress controller pod IP instead.
`externalIPs` can be list of your public IPs

you can find useful information about services and ingress in following links:
[Kubernetes Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)

[Nginx Ingress - Bare-metal considerations](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/)

Comment: I prefer using standard http/https ports (80/443). Also, when I am able to curl the services from inside I simply need to route incoming traffic to that ingress controller, if I am not wrong?

Comment: you're right, but in a Kubernetes cluster when you add a service and expose it, actually your making a route to your endpoints using that service

Comment: Okay, but I already have done whats behind your link with the bare-metal considerations. Is this what do you mean with `reverse proxy`? I can curl my pod's services as mentioned in the guide. Sorry, I am still a little bit confused about the terms.

Comment: You are curling from outside of the cluster or inside of cluster?
if outside so the problem solved and you need to install an Nginx or HA proxy and setup a reverse proxy to send requests to your Ingress Controller

Comment: I can curl the server from *outside of the cluster* but from *inside of the server*. Sorry, I hope this makes any sense :D. So in a nutshell: When I connect to the server (e.g. via ssh) I can curl the cluster.

Comment: so install an Nginx or HA proxy on your server and send all requests from port 80 of server to cluster

Comment: Thank you, you helped me a lot :) I will try this out later on :) Probably you can add this to your answer later on? :)